# Decrypt an tex file encrypted with rand()

Tags: c++, random, cryptography

[Question I'm trying to solve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZBRD.png)

The approach I want to take is to bruteforce all possible keys (seeds) until I find the right one. I know the first characters in the tex file so these are what I'm testing against. When I find the right sequence, I would stop the program and output the key.

```
/* The ISO/IEC 9899:1990 edition of the C standard */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

//#define RAND_MAX 32767
static unsigned long int next = 1;
int rand(void) // RAND_MAX assumed to be 32767
{
    next = next * 1103515245 + 12345;
    return (unsigned int)(next/65536) % 32768;
}
void srand(unsigned int seed)
{
    next = seed;
}

using namespace std;

//Return a byte at a time of the rand() keystream
 char randchar() { 
  static int key;
  static int i = 0;

  i = i % 4;
  if (i == 0) key = rand();
  return ((char *)(&key))[i++];
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {


  for (unsigned int i = time(NULL); i >= 0; i--) //Try all possible return values of time(NULL) since today
  {

      srand(i); 

      cout << "Trying with time(NULL) = " << i << endl;

      FILE *input, *output;
      input = fopen("Homework1b-Windows.tex.enc", "r");
      output = fopen("Homework1b.tex", "w");

      int c,rc, test;
      int pos;
      pos = 0;
      bool pos0, pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4, pos5;
      pos0 = pos1 = pos2 = pos3 = pos4 = pos5 = false;
      char temp1, temp2;

      while ((c = fgetc(input)) != EOF) {
        rc=randchar();
        fputc(c^rc,output);

        test = c^rc;

        temp1 = (char)test;


        temp2 = '\\';

        if ((pos == 0) && (temp1 == temp2))
        {
                 pos0 = true;
        } 

        temp2 = 'd';

        if ((pos == 1) && (temp1 == temp2))
        {
                 pos1 = true;
        }

        /*

        temp2 = 'o';

        if ((pos == 2) && (temp1 == temp2))
        {
                 pos2 = true;
        }

        temp2 = 'c';

        if ((pos == 3) && (temp1 == temp2))
        {
                 pos3 = true;
        }

        */

        temp2 = 'u';

        if ((pos == 4) && (temp1 == temp2))
        {
                 pos4 = true;
        }

        temp2 = 'm';
        if ((pos == 5) && (temp1 == temp2))
        {
                 pos5 = true;
        }

        pos++;

      }
      fclose(input);
      fclose(output);

      if (pos0 && pos1 && pos4 && pos5)
      {
         cout << endl << "Cracked. The seed is time(NULL) = " << i << endl;
         break;
      }
  }

  system("pause");


}
```

I know that the decrypted tex file starts with "\document".

The problem I'm facing is that the code never terminates. It never finds the right key (seed).

Any help?

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a [simplified code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Consider simply reading from input file and writing to another file to identify the issue faster

Comment: You should test your decoder with a known value, then test it when it's hunting for the value.

Comment: `for (unsigned int i = time(NULL); i >= 0; i--)` will loop forever, because i will always be greater than 0

Comment: This is homework. Debug, tract the execution watching the variables or go "Caveman" and add print statements. and/or Think, think about the execution, think through the program steps in your mind. This is how you learn.

Comment: Did you even read [fgrieu's comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/57884/decrypt-an-tex-file-encrypted-with-rand#comment127078_57884) before re-posting this question?  It clearly pointed out a bug "Not zeroing `randchar`'s variable `i` at each new decryption attempt?" which you didn't bother to fix.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is reasonable (brute force the key going back from "now" and looking for matching plain text), but your implementation can be improved.
For example, you shouldn't open and close the files inside the loop.

If you look at how `randchar()` is implemented, it is probably more efficient to call `rand()` directly, and compare four characters at a time.

In fact, you can compute the `xor` of the encrypted and plain text once, and simply compare the value returned by `rand()` to it.

To speed things up even more, you can write the first 8 character of encrypted and plain text directly in the source file, using a simple function to pack four `char` into an `int`:

```
int to_int(const char buffer[4]) {
  return (static_cast<int>(buffer[0])) + 
         (static_cast<int>(buffer[1]) <<  8) +
         (static_cast<int>(buffer[2]) << 16) +
         (static_cast<int>(buffer[3]) << 24);
}
```

and inside `main()`

```
  const int crypt1 = to_int("\x57\x12\x6f\x63");
  const int crypt2 = to_int("\x51\x59\x65\x6e");
  const int plain1 = to_int("\\doc");
  const int plain2 = to_int("umen");
  const int target1 = plain1 ^ crypt1;
  const int target2 = plain2 ^ crypt2;
```

Now what is left is to loop over all possible keys and look for a match (and as @Raxvan pointed out, you should not check for `key >= 0` or the loop will never complete):

```
  unsigned int key = time(nullptr);
  for (; key > 0; --key)
  {
      srand(key);
      if (rand() == target1 and rand() == target2) {
      std::cout << "key is 0x" << std::hex << key << std::endl;
      break;
      }
  }
  if (key == 0) {
      std::cout << "key not found" << std::endl;
  }
```